# Using Different elements for Laptop and Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

Framework: [Meteor](http://meteor.com)

**I am using Handlebars to send information to the client.**

I have this layout defined named post.html:

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator" src="{{image}}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><a href="/{{slug}}">{{title}}</a><i class="mdi-navigation-more-vert right"></i></span>

        <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{title}}<i class="mdi-navigation-close right"></i></span>
            <p class="tobeappeded">{{body}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice the `Card` layout.

Now this is responsive and works and I dont have a problem that How to make it responsive? It works.

I want to completely change this layout, and use other elements in the layout.

I know this can be done using JS by manipulating the DOM, and appending HTML, but can that be attained without JS?

Like maybe, the JS is `only` used to find the screen size, or something, and if it is, it renders layout number `1`, otherwise, it renders layout number `2`.

[ Think of it as Media Queries, but for HTML/JS]

You could also think about how `Fragments` work in Android.

Comment: Aren't you just asking how to hide/show elements with media queries with this?  It's simple.  Put both on the page.  When the screen width is above a certain point, show your alternate.  Below: show the cards.

Comment: I'll give a quick example of one way of doing this: For instance I want to display the avatar and log out link in the top right of my website on desktop, but inside the menu on mobile. Make a template for the avatar and include it in both places. Now use css classes e.g. `<div class="hide mobile">{{> avatarTemplate }}</div>` and `<div class="hide desktop">{{> avatarTemplate }}</div>`. Use media queries in the CSS to set `display:none` if the screen size doesn't match.

Comment: @JoshBurgess you beat me to it :)

Comment: I will try that and will letyou know.Sounds promising. And now the question looks simple too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `window.matchMedia()`, which is basically media queries in javascript. And if it matches your condition load your templates accordingly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia